# jQuery .hide() method and object.is(':hidden')

Tags: jquery, html

When I call `.hide()` on a jQuery object, the object gets a style of `display: none`. When you try to check if this object is hidden by `object.is(':hidden')`, it returns true, but when you try to check its first child using the same jQuery method, some return false while some return true.

Sample:

```
<div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="childContainer"></div>
    <p id="childContainer"></p>
</div>
```

```
$('#parentContainer').hide();

$("div[id='childContainer']").is(':hidden') // returns false
$("p[id='childContainer']").is(':hidden')   // returns true
```

Anyone have an idea why the behavior is like this?

Comment: $("div#childContainer").is(':hidden') is how you should select id in that second part... or since its just an id, and all IDs should be UNIQUE, you can write $('#childContainer').is(':hidden')

Comment: Don't have multiple elements with the same ID, for one.

Comment: They both return true for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/UpEjP/ tested in IE8/IE9/firefox 14.0.1 / Chrome 21.0.1180.60

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue to do with having two same ID's on the page.

Id in html should be unique if you have duplicates then you should use class, otherwise your code will not pass w3c validation etc.

Also in your post you put $("div[id='childContainer']").is(':hidden') --> returns false however when I tried it in jsfiddle I get true.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/kep7d/1/

Comment: Though you are correct.  The way he's selecting his elements would still work since he's specifying the element type

Comment: technically, the 'p' tag's id is different from the 'div' tag. sorry for the typo error.